# Extending Cmenu for changing default 'call' $this->menu in viewfile

Tags: yii, yii-components

I've extended the default CMenu,
When I want to use this extended version of CMenu I do the following: 
`$this->widget('application.components.translateCMenu',....`

This works for me, but in most of the CRUD generated view files the menuwidget is 'prepared' in an other way:

`$this->menu=array()`

I want to force yii to use my extended CMenu class instead of the default CMenu widget class for rendering the (operations) menu. How am I able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the auto-generated code to be custom in anyway then you would need to write your own [Gii templates](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii#extending-gii), which is very simple, and often recommended, so you can have the auto-generated code to fit your personal/company style.